# Loop rename variables in R with assign()

Tags: r, loops, rename, assign

I am trying to rename a variable over several data frames, but assign wont work. Here is the code I am trying

```
assign(colnames(eval(as.name(DataFrameX)))[[3]], "<- NewName")
# The idea is, go through every dataset, and change the name of column 3 to
# "NewName" in all of them
```

This won't return any error (All other versions I could think of returned some kind of error), but it doesn't change the variable name either.

I am using a loop to create several data frames and different variables within each, now I need to rename some of those variables so that the data frames can be merged in one at a later stage. All that works, except for the renaming. If I input myself the names of the dataframe and variables in a regular call with `colnames(DF)[[3]] <- "NewName"`, but somehow when I try to use assign so that it is done in a loop, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: do you have a `list` of `data frame`? Or what is the `class` of the variable in which you have several `data frame`?

Comment: They are not on a list, or grouped under any other variable. They are all independent, free-standing data-frames (I have seen that apparently the best way to do it is by using lists of data frames, but I would appreciate a solution without them)

Comment: I appreciate all answers, but if someone can tell my why the assign call is not working, that would also be great

Comment: Read `help("assign")`. It's unclear what your reasoning for your code is and why you believe it should work. Also, using a list is recommended for good reasons. Don't make your coding life harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do with a loop over all `data frames` in your environment. Since you are looking for just `data frame` in your environment, you are immune of the risk to touch any other variable. The point is that you should `assign` new changes to each `data frame` within the loop.

```
df1 <- data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3)
df2 <- data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3)
df3 <- data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3)

# > df1
  # q w e
# 1 1 2 3
# > df2
  # q w e
# 1 1 2 3
# > df3
  # q w e
# 1 1 2 3

DFs=names(which(sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame)))
for (i in 1:length(DFs)){
    df=get(paste0(DFs[i]))
    colnames(df)[3]="newName"
    assign(DFs[i], df)
}

# > df1
  # q w newName
# 1 1 2       3
# > df2
  # q w newName
# 1 1 2       3
# > df3
  # q w newName
# 1 1 2       3
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have other data frames on the workspace, so to save up effort I will try to re-write it so that it only calls on data frames with a certain naming structure, but for the rest that does it

Comment: In which case, you can filter out `DFs` using `grep` and your desired `regex` pattern. i.e., `DFs=grep("regex pattern wanted", DFs, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

We could try `?eapply()` to apply `setnames()` from the `data.table` package to all data.frame's in your global enviromnent.

```
library(data.table)
eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(x) if (is.data.frame(x)) setnames(x, 3, "NewName"))
```

Comment: I have plenty of other variables and data frames in my environment, and I would rather not do anything that might touch them, but I'll give a try to `setnames'

Comment: Why don't you save the relevant `data.frame`s in a list and use `lapply` then?

Comment: I would also update your question, because currently you say `#The idea is, go through every dataset`, hence the `eapply` approach.