# How to rename all variables using non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying top rename variables within the flow of work.
This problem occurs when I want to rename variables programmatically, and don't want to break the flow and perform an `names(df)<-namevect` operation.

see below for a minimal example that throws

> Error: All arguments to `rename()` must be named.

```
testdf <- mtcars %>% 
  rename_(.dots=make.names(1:11)) %>% 
  mutate(X3=X3*2)
```

Comment: use `setNames`, it makes it easier in a pipe, i.e. `mtcars %>% setNames(make.names(1:11)) %>% ...`

Comment: How about [this tread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526921/loop-rename-variables-in-r-with-assign)?

Comment: For the special case of renaming all variables with `X1, X2, ..., Xn` you can also use `select(mtcars, X = everything())`

Comment: This link also has some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502465/replacement-for-rename-in-dplyr

Comment: Thanks for the tip I changed to setNames. It's weird that it is such a struggle to use when everything else in dplyr is so smooth.